# How to join THREE different SQL queries having common column

Tags: mysql, sql

**1st Query:**

```
select MONTHNAME(batchStartDate) AS MONTHS,
    MONTH(batchStartDate) AS MONTHNUMBER,
    SUM(totalCandidatesInBatch) AS CANDIDATES_ENROLLED 
from batch 
group by MONTHS 
order by MONTHNUMBER;
```

**2nd Query:**

```
select MONTHNAME(resultApprovedOndate) AS MONTHS,
    MONTH(resultApprovedOndate) AS MONTHNUMBER,
    SUM(totalCertified) AS CANDIDATES_CERTIFIED 
from batch 
where totalPass is not null AND 
    totalFail is not null AND 
    resultApprovedOnDate<=curDate() and 
    resultApprovedOnDate is not null 
group by MONTHS 
order by MONTHNUMBER;
```

**3rd Query:**

```
select MONTHNAME(assessmentDate) AS MONTHS,
    MONTH(assessmentDate) AS MONTHNUMBER,
    (SUM(totalPass)+SUM(totalFail)) AS CANDIDATES_ASSESSED 
from batch 
where totalPass is not null AND 
    totalFail is not null AND 
    resultApprovedOnDate<=curDate() and 
    resultApprovedOnDate is not null 
group by MONTHS 
order by MONTHNUMBER;
```

As you can see these Queries have common column MONTHS and MONTHNUMBER , I want to join the result of these three queries.
I have tried UNION but that doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me what's happening and what could be the solution?

OUTPUT
**1st QUERY**

```
 # MONTHS, MONTHNUMBER, CANDIDATES_ENROLLED
 January,       1,       50
 February,      2,       35
 March,         3,       205
 April,         4,       85
 May,           5,       616
 June,          6,       26
```

**2nd QUERY**

```
 # MONTHS, MONTHNUMBER, CANDIDATES_CERTIFIED
  January,       1,            34
    April,       4,            72
     July,       7,            484
   August,       8,            30
```

**3rd QUERY**

```
 # MONTHS, MONTHNUMBER, CANDIDATES_ASSESSED
 February,       2,           101
    March,       3,           134
      May,       5,           32
     July,       7,           75
   August,       8,           75
September,       9,           150
  October,       10,           75
 November,       11,           77
 December,       12,          152
```

I want the output to be displayed in a form

```
# MONTHS, MONTHNUMBER, CANDIDATES_ENROLLED, CANDIDATES_CERTIFIED, CANDIDATES_ASSESSED
```

and also if a table has a Row Missing then the value should be filled with zero or null.Ex- In 3rd Query Output January is missing then candidates assessed should be 0 or null.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: Did you try using JOIN? lol

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be helpful.  Hard to know if you want to condense like-months into single records (`JOIN`), or have multiple records (`UNION`).

Comment: added sample data

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

It shows you the different types of joins (I'm assuming you want to do a "join").

Union is used to combine two or more sets on top of eachother.

Using join you can join based on a related column between your tables

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done with a single query:

```
select MONTHNAME(batchStartDate) AS `MONTHS`,
    MONTH(batchStartDate) AS `MONTHNUMBER`,
    SUM(totalCandidatesInBatch) AS `CANDIDATESE_ENROLLED`,
    SUM(
        IF(NOT(totalFail IS NULL) AND 
            NOT(totalFail IS NULL) AND 
            resultApprovedOnDate <= curDate() AND 
            NOT(resultApprovedOnDate is null),
            totalCertified,
            0
        ) AS `CANDIDATESE_CERTIFIED`,
    SUM(
        IF(NOT(totalFail IS NULL) AND 
            NOT(totalFail IS NULL) AND 
            resultApprovedOnDate <= curDate() AND 
            NOT(resultApprovedOnDate is null),
            totalPass + totalFail,
            0
        ) AS `CANDIDATESE_ASSESSED`
from batch 
group by MONTHS 
order by MONTHNUMBER;
```

Comment: getting Syntax Error please check